# Why are the red parts of this expression present $\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}\frac{dx^c}{\color{red}{d\lambda}}\frac{dx^d}{\color{red}{d\lambda}}}d\lambda$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, parametrization, geodesic, general-relativity

I am now trying to teach myself about geodesics, and a passage of my notes reads:

> In this chapter geodesics have been introduced as generalizations of straight lines through
> $$\frac{Du^a}{ds}=0$$
> Here two alternative characterizations of geodesics are considered.
>
> $(\mathrm{a})$ Consider a curve $C$ joining two fixed points $x_A$ and $x_B$. This can be defined through $x^a=x^a(\lambda)$, where $\lambda \in [a, b]$ is a parameter. The length of the curve can be expressed as an integral
> $$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}\frac{dx^c}{\color{red}{d\lambda}}\frac{dx^d}{\color{red}{d\lambda}}}d\lambda\tag{?}$$
> Geodesics may be deﬁned as curves that minimise (or maximise) $L$ for ﬁxed end points $x_A$ and $x_B$. The integral is awkward to work with due to the parametrisation ambiguity of the integral.

The second method, $(\mathrm{b})$ is no interest to what I have to ask here. The simple question I have is why are there the red parts in denominators of $(\mathrm{?})$. In other words, I think those denominators should be unity, $d\lambda=1$. I say this because from the equation for the differential line segment (squared):
$$ds^2=g_{cd} dx^c dx^d\tag{A}$$

Since the action, $$L=\int_{a}^{b} ds = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{g_{cd}dx^cdx^d}d\lambda\tag{B}$$ I think the notes are wrong and $(\mathrm{?})$ should actually be $$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{g_{cd}dx^cdx^d}d\lambda$$

I thought the above would be enough to convince others that this is all just another typo and I have the right expression, but sadly, I came across these handwritten notes, which I will embed as an image below:

Seeing this only makes me believe that I am the one making the mistake and that $(\mathrm{?})$ truly is correct.

So, how can $(\mathrm{?})$ possibly be correct when it is simply derived from taking the square root of $(\mathrm{A})$ [as in $(\mathrm{B})$]?

Comment: Your version doesn’t have the right units. (And where does the $d\lambda $ come from in the second step?)

Comment: You should look at the usual parametric curve case to see where you went wrong.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your reply, which part of my version doesn't have the right units? Can you show me which formula(s)?

Comment: @Cameron Which parametric curve is that?

Comment: $L$ and $ds$ have units of length. call the units of $\lambda$  “time”. Your expression has units of length times time, not length.

Comment: I'm referring to the arc length of a function versus a parametric curve. Treating $y$ as a function of $x$, your arc length integral is $$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx$$ but treating $x$ and $y$ as a function of a parameter $t$ (for time, perhaps), the arc length is $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}\,dt.$$ If you consult the derivation for the arc length of a parametric curve (which is effectively what you're doing but with a perhaps different metric), you'll see why having $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}d\lambda$ is wrong.

Comment: The derivation for the usual arc length of a parametric curve is very enlightening. I suggest looking it up to clear up the questions you've had across comments on this post.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Many thanks, do you have a link to this, please?

Comment: I found one! [Check this out.](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/11%3A_Parametric_Equations_and_Polar_Coordinates/11.2%3A_Calculus_of_Parametric_Curves) Scroll to about halfway down the page. The argument given here is more or less the argument I give my students in class. You can see how the derivative of both coordinates pops out and why it will happen in your setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrying your reasoning forward, since $ds^2=g_{cd}dx^cdx^d$, we'll get
$$
\int_a^b ds=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}dx^c dx^d}
=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}\frac{dx^c}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^d}{d\lambda}}d\lambda.
$$

Comment: Hi there, many thanks for your answer, are you simply multiplying top and bottom by $d\lambda$? If it's not that then please spell it out for me, I know it's bad that I can't even see what went wrong.

Comment: @FutureCop I think in your derivation there's a $d\lambda$ that appears in the integral that is not supposed to be there. In order to take $d\lambda$ out of the root, you have to divide the term under the root by $d\lambda^2.$

Comment: Okay, and does your answer take into account this extra $d \lambda$ under the square root sign in the integrand? I'm not sure I agree though, the $d\lambda$ is the integration variable, it was never under the square root, was it?

Comment: @FutureCop The $\lambda$ is not the integration variable in the middle integral. It wasn't under the square root, but in order to integrate with $\lambda$ as the integration variable you have to factor $d\lambda$ out of the root, meaning you have to divide it out.

Comment: What you say was just starting to make sense, but then you wrote "It wasn't under the square root, but in order to integrate with $\lambda$ as the integration variable you have to factor $d\lambda$ out of the root". But as you say, there was no $d\lambda$ under the square root.

Comment: Put simply you are saying, $\int_a^b ds=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}dx^c dx^d}
=\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{cd}\frac{dx^c}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^d}{d\lambda}{d\lambda}^2}.
$

Comment: @FutureCop There is no $x$ in the expression $y+z$. Nonetheless I can factor it out as $(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{z}{x})x$.

Comment: Yes, nicely explained though I think I got that part with my comment before it. I just don't understand why I am the only upvoter of your answer, your answer seems to address my point of confusion nicely and coupled with the comments below it, does a good job at explaining the origin of the $d\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a serious problem already in the first half of Equation (B):

$$ L \stackrel?= \int_a^b ds. $$

Strictly speaking, this integral that you wrote in the middle of Equation (B) is a simple single-variable integral that runs from $s=a$ to $s=b$ (that's what your notation means), evaluating to
$$ \int_a^b ds = b - a. $$

Surely that is not what you wanted to write. You want an integral where there's a variable $\lambda$ that goes from $\lambda = a$ to $\lambda = b.$
You might write that integral like this:
$$ L = \int_a^b \frac{ds}{d\lambda}\, d\lambda. $$

You also say that $ds^2=g_{cd}dx^cdx^d,$
which you later use to justify the substitution
$ds = \sqrt{g_{cd}dx^cdx^d}.$
That might be fine and well in the proper context, but in getting from
$\int_a^b \frac{ds}{d\lambda}\, d\lambda$ to
$\int_a^b \fbox{something else}\, d\lambda$
you need to replace $\frac{ds}{d\lambda},$ not just $ds.$

But if you accept that $ds^2 = g_{cd} dx^c dx^d$ you should also accept that
$$ \left(\frac{ds}{d\lambda}\right)^2
 = g_{cd} \frac{dx^c}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^d}{d\lambda}. $$

Now take the square root on both sides, substitute for $\frac{ds}{d\lambda}$
in $L = \int_a^b \frac{ds}{d\lambda}\, d\lambda,$
and you have the equation in your notes.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The sole reason I put $\int ds$ at the start of eqn $(\mathrm{B})$ was to show that I wanted the expression from $(\mathrm{A})$, though I agree that it was a mistake to put the $d\lambda$ as the integration variable, this is why the comments below the other answer shows the discussion on this.

Comment: Actually it is a mistake to put $ds$ as the integration variable in the integral as written, because (as I said) it means that $s$ ranges from $a$ to $b$ and the only possible value of the integral is $b - a.$ You may have seen an integral written like $\int_\gamma ds$ where $\gamma$ is a curve, which is fine. But once we know the curve is parameterized by $\lambda\in[a,b]$, in order to have an integral of the form $\int_a^b$ we want the variable of integration to be $\lambda$ and nothing else.

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks for explaining

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't you interpret $\int_a^b ds$ as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to the arclength function $s(x)$ so that it returns $s(b)-s(a)$? To be more clear I suppose one should say $\int_a^b ds(\lambda).$

Comment: @subrosar Good point. I hope it comes out the same in the end.